# MySQl using COUNT with CASE statement

Tags: mysql, sql

in my mysql database i have `instagram_actions_histories` table with two important column as `action_type` and `action_name`, now i want to use count and case statement to get count of `id`s column, for example:

count of all `id`s when `action_type` equal `1` and `action_name` equal 'like'

```
select `account_id`,

count(case when action_type = 1 and action_name='like' then id else 0 END) as `like`,
count(case when action_type = 1 and action_name='superLike' then id else 0 END) as `superLike`,
count(case when action_type = 2 then id else 0 END) as `follow`, 

from `instagram_actions_histories` 
where `instagram_actions_histories`.`account_id` in (1) 
group by `account_id`
```

unfortunately i get wrong result as all of outputs are same, for example:

```
account_id  like    superLike    follow
1           1282    1282         1282
```

correct result was should be:

```
account_id  like    superLike    follow
1           1282    20           10
```

Comment: Can you provide SQL code for your table with sample data, so we could try the query?

Comment: you have errors i nthe above sql. Trailing comma before the `from` clause and `id` rather than `account_id` in the `case` statements

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should count 1 for a match, and count `NULL` when there is no match:

```
SELECT
    account_id,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN action_type = 1 AND action_name = 'like' THEN 1 END) AS `like`,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN action_type = 1 AND action_name = 'superLike' THEN 1 END) AS superLike,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN action_type = 2 THEN 1 END) AS follow
FROM instagram_actions_histories
WHERE account_id IN (1)
GROUP BY account_id;
```

The problem with the current logic of your `CASE` expressions is that `COUNT` will count any non null value as one count.  So zero also would be counted.

Note that your current logic *would* have worked using `SUM` to take the conditional aggregations, e.g.

```
SUM(CASE WHEN action_type = 1 AND action_name = 'like'
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `like`
```

In this case, to turn off the aggregation for non matching records, we in fact can use zero, because summing zero does not affect the sum.